# Making a basic animation from symbols JavaScript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, animation, switch-statement, setinterval

I am trying to make a basic loading animation from /|- symbols by cycling through them with setInterval() and a switch statement. This code does not work, what is wrong with it?
This is the first time I have tried to use the setInterval() function, so have I used it incorrectly?

```
<body>
<button onClick = "time()">Start</button>
<p id = "display">\</p>
</body>
<script>
function time(){
    var timeVar = setInterval(function(){spinner();},300);
}
function spinner(){
    var phase = document.getElementById("display").value;
    switch(phase){
    case "|":
        document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "/";
        break;
    case "/":
        document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "-";
        break;
    case "-":
        document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "\";
        break;
    case "\":
        document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "|";
        break;
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean with `does not work`? What is/is not happening? Please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

Several problems here:

1. you have to write `"\\"`
2. you mixed `display` and `para`
3. You mixed `value`and `innerHTML`

Try:

```
<button onClick = "time()">Start</button>
<p id = "para">\</p>

<script>
    function time(){
        var timeVar = setInterval(function(){spinner();},300);
    }
    function spinner(){
        var phase = document.getElementById("para").innerHTML;
        switch(phase){
            case "|":
                document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "/";
                break;
            case "/":
                document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "-";
                break;
            case "-":
                document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "\\";
                break;
            case "\\":
                document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "|";
                break;
        }
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/y8shfpk6/

replace `para` to `display` in switch statement

```js
function time() {
  var timeVar = setInterval(function() {
    spinner();
  }, 300);
}

function spinner() {
  var phase = document.getElementById("display").innerHTML;
  //console.log(phase)
  switch (phase) {
    case "|":
      document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "/";
      break;
    case "/":
      document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "-";
      break;
    case "-":
      document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "\\";
      break;
    case "\\":
      document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "|";
      break;
  }
};
```

```html
<button onClick="time()">Start</button>
<p id="display">\</p>
```